# Can't save many-to-many relations by form in JSP

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, model-view-controller, many-to-many

### The Context

I have a simple workshop application with three entities - `Job`, `Employee` and `Customer`. I am trying to create web interface which will add new `Job` in this case. Job has many to many relations with `Employee` and `Customer`. In `Job` entity there are lists of `Employee` and `Customer` as well.

### The Problem

When I try to post my request with new `Job` through HTTP I get Bad Request 400 with description:

> The server cannot or will not process the request due to something
>   that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request
>   syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request
>   routing).

I don't know where excactly is bug.

Forms for adding `Customer` and `Employee` work fine.

### The Code

**Entities:**

- Employee

  ```
  @Component
  @Entity
  public class Employee {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;
  @Pattern (regexp="[a-zA-Z]+")
  @NotEmpty
  private String employeeName;
  @Pattern (regexp="[a-zA-Z]+")
  @NotEmpty
  private String employeeSurname;
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "employeeList")
  private List<Job> jobList;


  public Employee() {
  }

  public Employee(int id, String employeeName, String employeeSurname) {
      this.id = id;
      this.employeeName = employeeName;
      this.employeeSurname = employeeSurname;

  }

  public Employee(String employeeName, String employeeSurname) {
      this.employeeName = employeeName;
      this.employeeSurname = employeeSurname;
      }

  public List<Job> getJobList() {
      return jobList;
  }

  public void setJobList(List<Job> jobList) {
      this.jobList = jobList;
  }
  public String getEmployeeName() {
      return employeeName;
  }

  public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
      this.employeeName = employeeName;
  }

  public String getEmployeeSurname() {
      return employeeSurname;
  }

  public void setEmployeeSurname(String employeeSurname) {
      this.employeeSurname = employeeSurname;
  }

  public int getId() {
      return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
  }}
  ```
- Customer

  ```
  @Component
  @Entity
  public class Customer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;
  @Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z]+")
  @NotEmpty
  private String CustomerName;
  @Pattern (regexp="[a-zA-Z]+")
  @NotEmpty
  private String CustomerSurname;
  @Pattern (regexp = "\\w+")
  @NotEmpty
  private String car;
  private int phonenumber;
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "customerList")
  private List<Job> jobList;

  public Customer(String customerName, String customerSurname, String car, int phonenumber) {
      CustomerName = customerName;
      CustomerSurname = customerSurname;
      this.car = car;
      this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
  }

  public Customer(int id, String customerName, String customerSurname, String car, int phonenumber) {
      this.id=id;
      CustomerName = customerName;
      CustomerSurname = customerSurname;
      this.car = car;
      this.phonenumber = phonenumber;

  }

  public Customer() {
  }

  public List<Job> getJobList() {
      return jobList;
  }

  public void setJobList(List<Job> jobList) {
      this.jobList = jobList;
  }

  public String getCustomerName() {
      return CustomerName;
  }

  public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
      CustomerName = customerName;
  }

  public String getCustomerSurname() {
      return CustomerSurname;
  }

  public void setCustomerSurname(String customerSurname) {
      CustomerSurname = customerSurname;
  }

  public int getPhonenumber() {
      return phonenumber;
  }

  public void setPhonenumber(int phonenumber) {
      this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
  }

  public String getCar() {
      return car;
  }

  public void setCar(String car) {
      this.car = car;
  }

  public int getId() {
      return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
  }}
  ```
- Job

  ```
  @Component
  @Entity
  public class Job {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @NotEmpty
  @Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z]+")
  private String jobName;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Employee> employeeList;


  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  @ManyToMany
  private List<Customer> customerList;

  public Job() {
  }

  public Job(String jobName, List<Employee> employeeList, List<Customer> customerList) {
      this.jobName = jobName;
      this.employeeList = employeeList;
      this.customerList = customerList;
  }



  public long getId() {
      return id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
      this.id = id;
  }

  public String getJobName() {
      return jobName;
  }

  public void setJobName(String jobName) {
      this.jobName = jobName;
  }

  public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
      return employeeList;
  }

  public void setEmployeeList(List<Employee> employeeList) {
      this.employeeList = employeeList;
  }

  public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
      return customerList;
  }

  public void setCustomerList(List<Customer> customerList) {
      this.customerList = customerList;
  }}
  ```

**DaoImpl**

- JobDaoImpl

  ```
  @Repository
  public class JobDaoImpl implements JobDao {

  @PersistenceContext
  EntityManager entityManager;

  @Override
  public List<Job> findAllJobs() {
      return entityManager.createQuery("select j from Job j order by j.id", Job.class)
              .getResultList();
  }

  @Override
  public Job addJob(Job job) {
      entityManager.persist(job);
      entityManager.flush();
      entityManager.refresh(job);
      return job;

  }}
  ```

**Service**

- JobService

  ```
  @Service
  @Transactional
  public class JobService {

  private JobDao jobDao;

  public List<Job> findAllJobs(){
      return jobDao.findAllJobs();
  }

  public Job addNewJob(Job job){return jobDao.addJob(job);}

  public JobService(JobDao jobDao) {
      this.jobDao = jobDao;
  }
  ```

  }

**Controller**

- JobController

  ```
  @Controller
  public class JobController {

  JobService jobService;
  EmployeeService employeeService;
  CustomerService customerService;

  public JobController(JobService jobService, EmployeeService employeeService, CustomerService customerService) {
      this.jobService = jobService;
      this.employeeService = employeeService;
      this.customerService = customerService;
  }

  //JOB INDEX
  @RequestMapping("job-index.html")
  public ModelAndView getJobIndex() {
      ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("jobViews/jobIndex");
      return modelAndView;
  }
  //SHOW EMPLOYEES
  @RequestMapping("show-jobs.html")
  public ModelAndView getAllJobs() {
      ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("jobViews/jobs");
      modelAndView.addObject("jobs", jobService.findAllJobs());
      return modelAndView;
  }

  //ADD NEW JOB GET METHOD
  @GetMapping(value = "add-job.html")
  public ModelAndView addNewJob(){
      return new ModelAndView("jobViews/addJob","job", new Job());
  }

  //ADD NEW JOB POST METHOD
  @PostMapping(value = "add-job.html")
  public ModelAndView addNewJob(@ModelAttribute Job job){
      return new ModelAndView("jobViews/addJobConfirmation","job",job);
  }

  @ModelAttribute("employeeInit")
  public List<Employee> initializeEmployees() {
      return employeeService.findAllEmployee();
  }

  @ModelAttribute("customerInit")
  public List<Customer> initializeCustomer(){ return customerService.findAllCustomer();}}
  ```

**JSP Views**

- addJob.jsp

  ```
  <f:form method="post" modelAttribute="job">

  <p>Job name:<f:input path="jobName"/></p>

  <f:hidden path="id"/>

  <f:select path="employeeList" multiple="true">
      <f:options items="${employeeInit}" itemLabel="employeeSurname" itemValue="id"></f:options>
  </f:select>

  <f:select path="customerList" multiple="true">
      <f:options items="${customerInit}" itemLabel="customerSurname" itemValue="id"></f:options>
  </f:select>

  <button type="submit">Add</button>
  ```

Comment: You first need to fix your entity model. You'll need to understand how @ManyToMany is used in JPA along with join tables: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html

Comment: Thanks Luay. I have forgotten about that. I added @ManyToMany annotation to Customer and Employee entities, but I still have same problem as before.